# Is it correct to say "almost whole" at the end of a sentence referring to a singular noun?

Tags: grammar

Is the second sentence correct?

"I ate the whole pie. I mean almost whole."

Answer (score 3):

Not really.  You could try:

"I ate the whole pie.  I mean almost all of it."

or better:

"I ate the whole pie. Well, nearly all of it"